# How to keep using 3rd app admin templates after customizations of admin.py?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, photologue

I use `django-photologue` and extended it:

```
# gallery.models.py
from photologue.models import Photo
from profiles.models import UserProfile

class PhotoExtended(Photo):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# gallery.admin.py
from photologue.admin import PhotoAdmin as PhotoAdminDefault
from photologue.models import Photo

from .models import PhotoExtended

class PhotoAdmin(PhotoAdminDefault):
    save_on_top = True

admin.site.unregister(Photo)
admin.site.register(PhotoExtended, PhotoAdmin)
```

`Photologue` has a feature to upload zip file with photos and it can be done using additional button in admin. After my changes this button disappeared.

Is it possible to use native `photologue`s admin templates in order to avoid copy-pasting them to my app's template folder? In `INSTALLED_APPS` `photologue` is higher than my `gallery` app

[Here](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/tree/35dea6a638ea17f3b30753934726caa0bdce0645/photologue/templates/admin/photologue/photo) there are the `photologue`s admin templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the path `templates/admin/photologue/photo/change_list.html`the part `photo` corresponds to the `Photo` model. You subclassed that model. The new model name is `PhotoExtended` but there is no template in `templates/admin/photologue/photo_extend/change_list.html`.

Copy the `change_list.html` from photologue app into your own (app) template folder. Eg: `project/app/templates/admin/photologue/photo_extend/change_list.html`.

Alternatively you can also just create a new file and use include the old template:

```
# project/app/templates/admin/photologue/photo_extend/change_list.html
{% include 'admin/photologue/photo/change_list.html' %}
```

*Update:* Another alternative is to set (one of) the BaseModelAdmin properties:

```
# Custom templates (designed to be over-ridden in subclasses)
add_form_template = None
change_form_template = None
change_list_template = None
delete_confirmation_template = None
delete_selected_confirmation_template = None
object_history_template = None
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if `PhotoExtend` maps to `photo_extend` or `photoextend`.

Comment: `class PhotoAdmin(PhotoAdminDefault):
    save_on_top = True
    change_list_template = 'admin/photologue/photo/change_list.html'` works ideally. No needs to create a new file. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it works but the other alternatives are not bad. It just depends on your requirement. Obviously you only need the content of the original template. But if you need to modify the template a little more it might be better to just create the template file in the right directory and be done with it.